# "Error using get" using a 'addlistener' function in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, get, matlab-figure

I have a problem in a Matlab GUI code. Let say for instance that I want to display in the console the value of a slider cursor in the GUI. But the fact is that I want to display it in real time, eg at each position of the cursor even if the click is still on, while moving it.

For this, I read on internet that the 'addlistener' function could help me. I put it in the slider_CreateFcn function like this :

```
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   h=addlistener(hObject,'Value','PostSet',@(~,~)slider1_Callback)
```

Then, I added a simple disp function in the callback function, like this :

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    get(hObject,'value')
```

Running this code raise this error :

```
Warning: Error occurred while executing callback:
Error using get
Cannot find 'get' method for matlab.graphics.internal.GraphicsMetaProperty class.

Error in untitled>slider1_Callback (line xx)
get(hObject,'value')
```

If I remove the `addlistener` function, obviously the update is no more in real time, but I don't get the error message. So I think that the problem is directly coming from the `addlistener` function.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce the error with the provided code in R2016a.

Comment: Thank you excaza for your comment. But no, in guide gui, the slider callback is not executed during the movement of the slide, just once you released the mouse. I'm getting the error in matlab 2015a

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code that you posted isn't the code that is producing your error. I'm guessing that the code that yielded your error looked like this:

```
h = addlistener(hObject, 'Value', 'PostSet', @slider1_Callback);
```

In this instance, a meta property is passed as the first input argument to `slider1_Callback` which is giving you the immediate error you're seeing.

That being said, if you want to call `slider1_Callback` you need to craft an anonymous function which actually passes the correct type (and number) of inputs to the callback function. Here is one which does that.

```
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    h = addlistener(hObject, 'Value', 'PostSet', ...
                    @(src,evnt)slider1_Callback(hObject, [], handles))
end
```

The better thing to do though, is to just use a *separate* callback rather then the one that GUIDE creates for you. This gives you a little bit more flexibility. Also, if you just want to display the value you don't need all of the other inputs and you can actually inline the entire callback rather than having a separate function.

```
h = addlistener(hObject, 'Value', 'PostSet', @(s,e)disp(get(hObject, 'Value')));
```

And to show it in action:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! The method which consists in calling an external function in the addlistener function, instead of the automatically created callback function, works well. (and indeed, there was a misprint writen in my text above)